# How to init array of commands only when the each is finished?

Tags: node.js, loops, recursion, command-line-interface, child-process

I am new to JavaScript & coding, so couldn't find answers online. I want to create a Node CLI command that execute a bunch of commands, one after the other, but only if the previous is done:

```
#! /usr/bin/env node
let child_process = require('child_process')
let exe;
const commands = [
      {
         title: `Creating React App`,
         path: `npx create-react-app .`
      },
      {
         title: `Gitting`,
         path: `git init`
      }
   ];
commands.forEach(command => {
            exe = child_process.exec(`${command.path}`, {cwd: `.`});
            exe.stdout.pipe(process.stdout)
            exe.on('exit', function() {
               // now next
              process.exit()
            })
         });
```

How can I wait to "exit"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use promises and async/await, to run each command after previous is done.

So, make a function that runs command, waits for it to finish, and then runs next one. Setup commands counter to track when all commands are done.

here's the code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env node
let child_process = require('child_process')

const commands = [{
   title: `Creating React App`,
   path: `npx create-react-app .`
}, {
   title: `Gitting`,
   path: `git init`
}];


// command runner
const runCommand = (command) => {

   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      let exe = child_process.exec(`${command.path}`, {
         cwd: `.`
      });
      exe.stdout.pipe(process.stdout)
      exe.on('exit', function() {
         console.log('finished: ', command.title);
         // now next
         resolve();
      })
   });
};


// run command in series
(async() => {

   // setup commands counter
   let i = 0;

   for (const command of commands) {

      console.log('running', command.title);

      // wait for command to finish
      let done = await runCommand(command);

      // log done command
      i++;

      // check if all commands are done
      if (i === commands.length) {
         console.log('done');
         process.exit();
      }
   }
})();
```